# JFrame with a list that gives information

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlist

I have a question regarding `JFrame` with a list.
I created a help menu button. Now the thing is:

When clicked a new window pops up as should. In this window I want to have a list with some formulas by name. Once a formula in the list is clicked I want to display in the same screen what the formula stands for.

It has to be something like formulas on the left in a scrollable list and in the same screen on the right in some sort of text box the description of the clicked formula.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
menuItem = new JMenuItem("Help");
     menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
     menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
     {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
             {  

                 JFrame help = new JFrame("HELP");
                 help.setTitle("Help");
                 help.setSize(400,200);
                 help.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                 help.setDefaultCloseOperation(help.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                 help.setVisible(true);
                 help.add(label);            

                 String labels[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "x", "y"};
                 JList list = new JList(labels);
                 JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane (list);

                 Container contentPane = help.getContentPane();
                 contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);



             }
     });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your post and add valid code demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes a basic implementation.

**How the second (formula) window may look like**:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class FormulaWindow extends JDialog {

    public FormulaWindow(final Window parent) {
        super(parent, "Formula window", ModalityType.MODELESS);
        final Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(500, 400);
        final Map<String, String> formulaDescritions = new HashMap<>();
        formulaDescritions.put("Formula 1", "<html>How the world works.</html>");
        formulaDescritions.put("Formula 2", "<html>How woman work.</html>");
        formulaDescritions.put("Formula 3", "<html>How programming works.</html>");
        final JList<String> formulaList = new JList<String>(new Vector<String>(formulaDescritions.keySet()));
        formulaList.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        final JLabel descriptionLabel = new JLabel();
        descriptionLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        formulaList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                final JList<String> list = (JList<String>) evt.getSource();
                descriptionLabel.setText(formulaDescritions.get(list.getSelectedValue()));
            }
        });
        cp.add(new JScrollPane(formulaList), BorderLayout.WEST);
        cp.add(new JScrollPane(descriptionLabel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

**How to open it on selection of a menu item in the main window**:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private class ShowFormulaWindowAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ShowFormulaWindowAction() {
            super("Show formulas...");
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            FormulaWindow formulaWindow = new FormulaWindow(MainWindow.this);
            formulaWindow.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public MainWindow() {
        super("Main window");
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Extras");
        fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem(new ShowFormulaWindowAction()));
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
                mainWindow.setSize(350, 250);
                mainWindow.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Further notes**:

The secondary window should not be a `JFrame` but rather a `JDialog`. In that way

- it does not show another icon on the task bar
- it can be "owned" by the main window, causing the dialog to be closed automatically, when the owner is closed

Comment: Is it possible to put the main inside the formulawindow. Because this has to happen when the button is clicked. Im making a spreadsheet program and this function will ben listed under help.

Comment: @user3105297: you can move this to the other class of course. I added an example of how to integrate it in your main application window.

Comment: Okay thank you. But is it possible to call FormulaWindow(), inside my ActionPerformed?

Comment: That doesnt work because inside my actionPerformed i cant make "new" formula window. So can i preset the setSize and setVisible inside the FormulaWindow()? So that i only have to call FormulaWindow inside my action performed.

Comment: What keeps you from making a `new FormulaWindow()` inside the `actionPerformed()` method? Moving the `setSize`call to the constructor makes sense. The invocation of `setVisible()` shouldn't be part the constructor ...

Comment: My code is now something like: ... menubuttons with actionperformed and within the same class it has the FormulaWindow(). It doesnt find the FormulaWindow method because it searches for a class.

Comment: Make the constructor public and add an import statement for the class in the other file.

Comment: Again the secondary window should not be a JFrame but rather a JDialog. There are several reasons for this, but most important, the dialog window is not a true independent application, but rather a subsidiary window of the main application. It should not show another icon on the task bar, it should not threaten to close the main application if it is closed...

Comment: I'll 1+ you for the change, but really, you should pass the parent window into your dialog class's constructor and use it to call an appropriate JDialog super constructor. Myself, I rarely extend JFrame or JDialog, but rather make them when needed and then stuff my GUI component (usually a JPanel) into the top-level window.

Comment: I completely agree with you and updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Suggestions:

- The help menu that pops up should be a dialog of some sort, perhaps a non-modal JDialog.
- You should have it use a CardLayout so that it initially shows formula names, perhaps in a JList held by a JScrollPane.
- When a JList item is selected, swap views via the CardLayout and display the appropriate formula.

Links:

- [CardLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- [JList Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

  ---

**Edit**
You state in comment,

> It has to be something like i have my formulas on the left with a scrollbar, and in the right side of the screen some sort of textbox with the description of the formula.

Shouldn't this any any other pertinent information and restrictions be part of your original question? If I were you, I'd edit the original post and supply all necessary information so that we can fully understand your problem including pertinent code (best as an [sscce](http://sscce.org)).  So...

- Use another layout manager such as a GridLayout or better yet a BorderLayout to allow you to show multiple JPanels in another JPanel. I'll leave it to you to find the links to the Swing layout manager tutorials.
- You can still use a CardLayout to swap the equations shown on the display JPanel.

---

**Edit 2**
Regarding your latest code post:

- Again, the dialog window should be a **JDialog** not a **JFrame**. The window is dependent on the window that is displaying it and so should not be an independent application window such as a JFrame.
- I'd place the JScrollPane in the BorderLayout.LINE_START position and the CardLayout using equation JPanel in the BorderLayout.CENTER position.
- You don't have to use a CardLayout. If the equations are nothing but basic text, you can simply change the text of a JLabel.
- Or if images, then swap the ImageIcon of a JLabel.
- Or if a lot of text, then text in a non-editable, non-focusable JTextArea

  ---

**Edit 3**

> is there a way to set the size to a fixed size of the scrollpane BorderLayout.LINE_START?

Rather than trying to set the size of anything, consider calling some methods on your JList, methods such as, `setPrototypeCellValue(E prototypeCellValue)` and `setVisibleRowCount(int visibleRowCount)` which will allow the component to set its own preferredSize based on reasonable data and initial assumptions. Please check the [JList API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) for the details on these and other JList methods.

Comment: It has to be something like i have my formulas on the left with a scrollbar, and in the right side of the screen some sort of textbox with the description of the formula.

Comment: is there a way to set the size to a fixed size of the scrollpane BorderLayout.LINE_START?

Comment: @user3105297: please see Edit 3 to answer.